# Google Analytics events not showing any reports

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have added the google analytics tracking code, it looks like this:

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

Now, I want to implement some events GA. I got this code, found on google:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'User Manual Download', 'PDF Download', 'Name');
```

and I have added it to the function that invokes on button click (button for downloading)

this is the function:

```
function download()
            {
                ga('send', 'event', 'User Manual Download', 'PDF Download', 'Name');

                document.getElementById("download-manual").style.boxShadow = " 0px 0px 30px #FFFFFF";
                setTimeout(function()
                {
                    document.getElementById("download-manual").style.boxShadow = " 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF";
                }
                , 200);
            }
```

The function is called everytime, there is no bugs, but event is not loaded to google analytics. In reports, I don't see any type of events at all. I have been waiting for about 12 hours for them to show up, but they don't show, and also in real time report, they don't appear. I am sure that download() function starts, bacause the button "flashes" (because of the box shadow). Where did I go wrong?

Comment: try to check weather ga is being reported or not using google-analytics-debugger chrome plugin. it shows output in console

Comment: @Nitin9791 I used the debugger and all was okay, but now I changed the code a bit and all works well. Thanks for suggesting the debugger, it is good tool.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work somehow. I still don't know what the problem was, I used debugger and it was all okay all along. Now, I just adjusted my code a bit, so it looks like this now:

```
ga('send', {
                  'hitType': 'event',
                  'eventCategory': 'User Manual Download',
                  'eventAction': 'PDF Download',
                  'eventLabel': 'Name',
                  'useBeacon': true,
                  'hitCallback': function() {
                    googleSent = true;
                  }
                });
```

somehow, it works.